# When causing the MUI Drawer component to open during a test, how to fix "An update to Transition inside a test was not wrapped in act(...)"?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, enzyme, react-testing-library

I have test code like this:

```
await act(() => {
  component.setProps({ location: { hash: '#audit-trail' } });
});
```

The component being tested renders a MUI Drawer, like so:

```
<Drawer
  anchor='right'
  open={this.props.location.hash.startsWith(`#audit-trail`)}
```

So the test code inside the act() block triggers the Drawer to open. But it seems like the Transition is happening asynchronously outside the scope of act(), and so I'm getting this annoying warning. Any solution to this? Even passing `transitionDuration={0}` to the Drawer didn't help.

Thanks!